# How can we insert values from one database to another where the database base names are same and hosts are different

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how can we insert values from one database to another where the database names are same and host  are different

```
INSERT INTO db.mt_magazine_subscription ( 
  magazine_subscription_id, 
  subscription_name, 
  magazine_id, 
  status ) 
SELECT db.magazine_subscription_id, 
   subscription_name, 
   magazine_id, 
   '1'
 FROM tbl_magazine_subscription
```

Both the databases are hosted on different server hosts.

Comment: I'd make a backup of the origin schema, restore it with another name in the same database as the target schema and make the insert being in the same database

Comment: Yes the DB names are same but the hosts are different, one is production db and another is a developer db

Comment: That would mean the mysql server would have to have a connection to another mysql server. I don't know if that's even possible. This would probably have to be done via the cli with mysqladmin, maybe even via a dump. 
I suggest a client like phpMyAdmin (can have more servers connected) with which you can export even individual rows and insert them into a different database on a different host.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways(like CLI Script, PHP script, crone job) but it depends on you, which way is suitable for you.

In PHP you can manage multiple connection like this.

```
     $dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
     $dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
```

And you can select any database and run query like this

```
    mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
    mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);

    mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
    mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

So the algo is 
Step1 : Make a connection with both database server $dbh1, $dbh2
Step2 : Select/get table data from one database by $dbh1
Step3 : Insert data(get from $dbh1) in second database by $dbh2

You can set this script like crone job.
I hope this will help you.